# Problems loading Gymnasyum environment and using it on my custom agent

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have problems reloading my environment's data. I have been doing some tests to see what is happening, and I have seen that the problem seems to be when using the environment inside the agent's methods. For instance:

```
print("Initializing env...")
gym_env = MyEnv(driver)

agent = PPOAgent(gym_env, model_name=tb_log_name, model_type=PPO, policy_string="MlpPolicy")

print("Printing the environment before backup")
agent.env.render_environment()
with open("back.pickle", 'rb') as file:
    state_dict = pickle.load(file)
agent.env.restore(state_dict)

print("Printing the environment after backup")
agent.env.render_environment()
agent.env.test()

print("Printing the environment after backup from inside the agent")
# If I do agent.env.step(0), the print is correct, but if I call train_agent, which internally calls model.learn() and this calls the step() method, the environment printed is the default one (not the one got by the backup), where reward is 0 instead of the value stored in the pickle file
agent.train_agent()
```

In all cases the printed environment has the information loaded from the pickle file, but if I call the train method from the agent (that internally calls step method), the printed environment is the default one (without loading the file's information). The weird thing is that some of those attributes are actually printed fine but others are not, here is an example:

This is the default environment printed at first:

```
 ---- Envrionent current information ----
   ... 
 - current_episode: 0
 - current_step: 0
 - errors: []
 - reward: 0
```

This is the one printed after the backup

```
 ---- Envrionent current information ----
   ... 
  - current_episode: 1 # new value
  - current_step: 12 # new value
  - errors: [{'uid': 162, 'k_uid': 3, 'type': 3, 'Error_text': "sdqweqweref9u9u23nkm,n", 'Error_image': ''}] # new value
  - reward: 222222 # new value
```

And this last one when printing it on the learn method:

```
 ---- Envrionent current information ----
   ... 
  - current_episode: 1 # This value is correctly loaded
  - current_step: 0 # This one is not
  - errors: [{'uid': 162, 'k_uid': 3, 'type': 3, 'Error_text': "sdqweqweref9u9u23nkm,n", 'Error_image': ''}] # This value is correctly loaded
  - reward: 0 # This one is not
```

I would like to understand how this happens and also a way to ensure the environment used by the learn method is equal to the one initialized by using the backup file.

These are the methods I use inside my environmet

```
def backup(self):
    state_dict = {}
    for key, value in vars(self).items():            
        state_dict[key] = value
    return state_dict

def restore(self, state_dict):
    for key, value in state_dict.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
        
def render_environment(self):
    print(" ---- Envrionent current information ----")
    for key, value in vars(self).items():
        print(f"  - {key}: {value}") 

def test(self):
    print("-- TESTING --")
    self.render_environment()
    # sys.exit()
```

Comment: Didn't you implement a "reset" method in your env?